# Story about a shepherd who prays to God but not using traditional prayers?

Tags: agada-stories-legends

I'm looking for the story about a shepherd who prayed to G-d using only his own prayers.  When a rabbi heard him praying one day he decided to teach him to pray using only traditional Jewish prayers. After the rabbi taught the shepherd the traditional prayers and moved on, the shepherd forgot the traditional prayers. The shepherd was embarrassed by this so he stopped praying all together.  G-d noticed the shepherd had stopped praying and was disappointed because G-d liked the shepherd's singing.  Does anyone know this story or have a link to it.

Comment: similar to the stories alluded to here? https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/abba-can-you-hear-me/

Comment: Definitely close, especially the first one about the wolf cry, but not exactly.  I know for sure the story I am thinking of exists, because I found it about 10 years ago in a collection of children's stories online. For the life of me can't find it anymore. It was a story my rabbi told me when I was very young.

Comment: Shivche Baal Shem Tov is the book from which comes this story.